# Filling datagridview : foreach vs datasource binding

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Until know I used `Datatable` to return value from my repository project to retrieve values from sql server.

But I have read and learned that It is better to use DTO's as returning value.

What is the more efficient way to fill the datagridview, because now I have a list of class as source.

Should I use a foreach loop on the list and manually add rows or create a datatable from the list and bind it to the datagridview?

Update :
for exemple, I have a list of class `User` and Id and Name as properties. I want to display just the name. I cannot bind directly the list. So I would need a datatable.

Now what is more efficient. Create this datatable and bind it, or fill dirctly the datagridview with a foreach loop?

Comment: As far as I remember, the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView` is of type `object`. This means that you can simply use the list as your datasource.

Comment: why don't you do a google search on the following `DataTable.Fill()`  method

Comment: you can bind to the list, create your own column for that one field you want to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show only part of the list you are binding to

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace datagridview_47800424
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<dgventry> dgvsource = new List<dgventry>();
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ourinit();
        }

        private void ourinit()
        {

            //lets create some records in that list
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgvsource.Add(new dgventry { name = $"name {i}", id = i });
            }


            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;//don't auto create the columns
            DataGridViewColumn dgvcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();//make your own
            dgvcol.DataPropertyName = "name";//set which property to bind to
            dgv.Columns.Add(dgvcol);//add the col to the grid


            dgv.DataSource = dgvsource;//bind the grid to your list

            this.Controls.Add(dgv);//add the grid to the form
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;//just need to position it somehow and this is quick

        }
    }


    public class dgventry
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gadsweb, if you use a `BindingList<>` instead of a `List<>` then most of the updates you will do to your DataSource will automatically be reflected in the display of the grid. So you can have a more fluent workflow and not have to code stuff that has been coded and tested already. If you want to try that out using my sample, you will need to add a `using System.ComponentModel;` at the top

Answer (score 0):

I did some benchmark.

The fastest way is to read datas from database with a datareader, then create the list of class.
After that binding directly the list to the datagridview and choose columns to display as mentioned by blaze.

The trouble is that datagridview cannot bind child objects properties.

A trick is to implement a public property to get the child class property and use this property in the `DataPropertyName` of the column.

This way is 5 or 6 times faster that a foreach loop and a little bit faster than using a datatable.

Hope this help and many thanks for your suggestions.

```
public class SubDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
public class DTO
{
    public int SubDtoId
    {
        get
        {
            return SubDTO.Id;
        }
    }
    public string SubDtoLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return SubDto.Label;
        }
    }
    public string Caract { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public SubDTO SubDTO { get; set; }
}
```

**The code to fill the datagridview**

```
    public Fill()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        DataGridViewColumn dgvcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dgvcol.DataPropertyName = "SubDtoId";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvcol);

        dgvcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dgvcol.DataPropertyName = "SubDtoLabel";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvcol);

        dgvcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dgvcol.DataPropertyName = "Caract";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvcol);
        dgvcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dgvcol.DataPropertyName = "Serial";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvcol);
        dgvcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dgvcol.DataPropertyName = "Comment";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvcol);


        dataGridView1.DataSource = ListOfClasses();

    }

    public List<DTO> ListOfClasses()
    {
     //Sql query to return the List of DTO
    }
```

Comment: then, please post some code in this answer, and accept your own instead of mine.